# Catch data in php script sent via Ajax and jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

I cannot seem to recuperate data being sent to a php script.
Upon monitoring chrome tools (networks->xhr->headers) the Content-length also give 0.

And under the Response tab, errors are as such:

"Automatically populating $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is deprecated and will be removed in a future version."
"Cannot modify header information - headers already sent in **Unknown** on line **0**"

Code that triggers jQuery/Ajax POST (on index.html):
var name = "john";

```
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
contentType: 'application/json',
url: "http://localhost:8000//mobile/hi.php",
date: name,
success: function(){alert("sent");}
});
```

And the php file which is on a separate page (hi.php):

```
<?php
$data = $_POST['name'] or $_REQUEST['name'];
echo $data;
?>
```

How do I go about simple catching the data sent into a php variable?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You're not using jQuery Ajax correctly :

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:8000/mobile/hi.php",
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        name: name
    },
    success: function(){
        alert("sent");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks @T'lash! Two questions: If I wanted to sent a json object, I'd use in the data field: data: {json : objName} ?

Comment: and do you know how to recuperate the sent data in the php script?

Comment: A JSON object is a JavaScript object, so you simply have to put it in the data object. To use it, you must deserialize it to a PHP object with the json_decode($_POST['json']) function. You can also serialize your response with json_encode($your_response).